# Removing Magura HS11 rim brake (hydraulic) without quick release lever

Tags: rim-brake, magura

My previous Magura HS11 hydraulic rim brakes had q/r levers, but my latest (s/h) Gazelle does not.

Which bolt do I remove to remove the brake from the fork to remove/replace the wheel and/or the brake blocks?

Can I fit q/r levers to make it easier in future?

Comment: Loosen the cable.

Comment: @DanielRHicks: Magura HS11 rim brakes are hydraulic brakes!

Comment: Can you clarify what model of brakes you currently have? If they are HS11s, the release lever should be on the brake itself, according to Magura's technical manuals. It's possible that there's some sort of release lever on the brake lever - Campagnolo mechanical groups have this - but I'm not sure how it would work with a hydraulic system.

Comment: It would help to know what model your Gazelle is, then the Gazelle website will show the bicycle specs (and brakes) are supplied with the bike... I found a a few Gazelle with rim brakes. The Gazelle Ultimate C8 comes with HS22. Searching for HS22 brakes on the Magura website has images and full specs how to operate your new brakes - https://www.magura.com/

Comment: Thanks, guys, it is a Gazelle Chamonix electric T10 HMB, a few years old.

Comment: My old Kalkhoff (crack in frame) also has HS11 brakes but with a Q/R lever, so I may try to swap them over. On reflection, the bolt to remove the brake assembly has to be the bolt that screws into the boss on the forks - I’ll take a closer look when it’s not so cold.

Comment: What about the wheel requires wider-spaced brake pads for removal?  Do you have a tyre that is wider than the rim?

Comment: Yes, Crigge, the rim is very narrow and I can only get the wheel out, through the brake blocks, by deflating the tyre, which is why I want to be able to remove the brake mechanism itself from the fork - which is what the q/r lever enables you to do!

Answer (score 1):

To undo the bolt attaching the brake mechanism to the fork, you need a Torx 25 star-shaped bit.

I had one in my toolbox, but they are readily available at DIY shops - just google ‘torx 25 bit’

There are two bolts on the brake mech, but it is only the bottom bolt which screws into the shoulder/boss on the fork, I didn’t touch the top bolt.

Removing the bolt enables you to lift the brake mech off the fork **on one side**, and the wheel can then be removed without deflating it - I have fitted wider schwalbe marathon 700/35mm tyres, but needed the mudguards moving slightly so they didn’t touch.

The brake mech bolts back on easily, and seems to need no adjustment.  I keep a torx bit and screwdriver bit holder in my bike bag now in case of any more punctures.

I've also fitted ‘Slime’ innertubes to reduce the chance of a puncture.

[image]